# things I don't get in python. bounded method acting like an alien

Tags: python, oop

I don't understang this behaviour, I changed 'r' on the class 'f' and it is reflected back
on 'q' as you can see 'q.r' indicates that it is now referencing a 'lambda' function but at the same time the adress is always '0x037591F0' so why 'q.r()' is failling?

```
class f:
    def r(self):
        print('bla bla bla')

>>> q=f()
>>> f.r
<function f.r at 0x0378F4B0>
>>> q.r
<bound method f.r of <__main__.f object at 0x037591F0>>
>>> f.r=lambda : 'google'
>>> f.r
<function <lambda> at 0x015F9348>
>>> q.r
<bound method <lambda> of <__main__.f object at 0x037591F0>>
>>> q.r()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Comment: Your two bound methods did not exist at the same time, so it's quite possible (but not guaranteed, or anything you should care about) that the second one reused the same memory address as the first one.  They are clearly not the same object, they have a different number of parameters for one thing.

Comment: Your lambda does not take ```self``` as a parameter. When you call a method via an instance (```q.r()```), the "caller" is inserted into the "self" parameter

Comment: @MichaelBianconi I know this but why the adress is the same as that is not the case for 'f.r'

Comment: `f` is a class and `q` is an object. `f.r()` acts as a staticmethod but when calling `q.r()`, q passes itself as an argument of `r`.

Comment: Read the [Descriptor How-to guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html). It explains the descriptor protocol, which `function` objects implement, and explains why methods behave the way they do. (Namely, why are `q.r()` and `f.r(q)` the same?)

Comment: The short answer is: a `function`-valued class attribute accessed via an instance of the class is expected to take at least one argument: the instance that invoked the function.

Answer (score 1):

`r` is a class attribute whose value is a function. When you access it from an *instance* of the class, you don't actually get the `function` object back: you get back the result of the function's `__get__` method, which is a new `method` object. Further, every such access creates a *new* `method` object, but because that object is short-lived (basically, it exists long enough to be called, then it is garbage-collected), each new object can use the same memory as the previous one.

Comment: good...this seems to be the response => ".__get__." . Thank you guy

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand what is an instance method and how it works,
remember in Python the instance methods lives in the class not in the object for that reason Python pass the self parameter in implicit way in every instance method (to know what object is calling the method).

In your example the lambda function does not receive any parameters and you dont use the self parameter, so that tell us that the method must be a static method(unbound method) not an instance method(bounded method), in other words that "r" method need to be bound to the class and not to the object.

```
class f:
    @staticmethod
    def r():
        print('bla bla bla')
```

If stills confusing you read about the class methods, static methods and instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `r` doesn't even start out as a static method, but even if it did, when you assign a lambda to `r` on the class, you're replacing it and it will no longer be a static method. So, when Python calls it, it will pass `self` as the first parameter.

```
import inspect


class C:
    @staticmethod
    def r():
        return 'x'


print(isinstance(inspect.getmro(C)[0].__dict__['r'], staticmethod))
C.r = lambda: 'y'
print(isinstance(inspect.getmro(C)[0].__dict__['r'], staticmethod))
```

Result:

```
True
False
```